# Display seconds as minutes and seconds

Tags: python, time

I'm new to Python and a little confused on how to do something that is likely trivial.

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column containing time in seconds.

```
DF
ID Call_Duration
1 127
2 153
3 23
4 87
5 96
```

I'd like to display that as a new column showing time in minutes and seconds:
MM:SS

```
ID Call_Duration Minutes
1 127 02:07
2 153 02:33
3 23 00:23
4 87 01:27
5 96 01:36
```

I've tried using to_timedelta in pandas but it displays much more than I want (shows precision to days):

```
DF['Minutes'] = DF.to_timedelta(DF['Call_Duration'],unit="m")
```

I also found a function that would work for a single entry but not sure how to adapt it to work for a dataframe column instead of throwing it in a loop.

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using your `format_duration`, with dataframe.apply, specifying axis=1:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(frame)

def format_duration(row):
    seconds = row.Call_Duration  ## changed this
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)

frame['duration'] = frame.apply(format_duration, axis=1)
## now frame has a new column with the desired results
print(frame)

   ID  Call_Duration  duration
0   1            127  00:02:07
1   2            153  00:02:33
2   3             23  00:00:23
3   4             87  00:01:27
4   5             96  00:01:36
```

edit: I added some comments in the inline code. That should answer it- please let me know if not! thx

Comment: Cool. This is what I was looking for. I ended up using map instead though:
calls_out['minutes'] = calls_out['call_duration'].map(format_duration)

Comment: Great- glad you got it sorted. Please accept my answer if it was helpful in arriving at the solution.

Answer (score -1):

To convert seconds to minutes and seconds:

```
def separate(seconds):
    '''This functions separates seconds into a (minutes, seconds) tuple.'''

    return (
        floor(seconds / 60),   # devide by 60 and remove remainder
        remain  = seconds % 60 # take away 60 until less than 60 (modulo)
    )
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question: 'not sure how to adapt it to work for a dataframe column instead of throwing it in a loop.' i.e. So really it's a pandas dataframe question.

Comment: I don't really know. But this does give raw data, rather than displaying it.